# Adding move semantics to existing structure containing POD and non-POD members

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Let's say I have the following structure:

```
struct Test
{
    int n1;               // represents POD types, in real program
    int n2;               // I have much more data
    char str[STR_SIZE];
    vector<int> v;        // represents non-POD types
};
```

Now I add move semantics to it:

```
struct Test
{
    int n1;
    int n2;
    char str[STR_SIZE];
    vector<int> v;

    Test(){}

    Test(const Test& other) : v(other.v)
    {
        Copy(other);
    }

    Test(Test&& other) : v(move(other.v))
    {
        Copy(other);
    }

    Test& operator=(const Test& other)
    {
        if ( this != &other )
        {
            Copy(other); v = other.v;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Test& operator=(Test&& other)
    {
        if ( this != &other )
        {
            Copy(other); v = move(other.v);
        }
        return *this;
    }

private:
    void Copy(const Test& other)        // copy POD members
    {
        n1 = other.n1; n2 = other.n2;
        memcpy(str, other.str, sizeof(str));
    }
};
```

I am not quire happy with performance of the `Copy` function, which assigns all non-POD structure members. Is there better approach to make such transformation? I need to get maximal performance (such structures are kept in STL containers in the real program) and standard compliance. I can only think about placing all POD members in the beginning, and copying them using single `memcpy` call instead of `Copy` function, but this looks like a hack.

Currently I am working with VS2010 compiler.

Comment: Aside: You would be OK with defaulted copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: @juanchopanza - good point, but currently I cannot use this: VS2010 doesn't support it.

Comment: If I understand correctly from your previous question, VS2010 gives you the implicitly defined copy constructor and assignment operator anyway, no? So you could remove your own, and add `delete`d ones is and when you upgrade to a C++11 compliant compiler.

Comment: @juanchopanza: it looks like compiler-generated copy constructor contains series of assignment operations (looking Assembly in Release configuration). So I should not care about my `Copy` function. I will follow your advice by using compiler-generated functions in VS2010 and `= delete` for later compiler versions.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine all POD members in one struct and use [pimpl idiom](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/), so they can be also moved all together.

Comment: This needs heap allocation which may make things worse (depending on the value of STR_SIZE and the performance of the heap implementation).

Comment: @RüdigerStevens Depends on the application. If the focus is on moving data which was allocated only once it can be an improvement. If the algorithm makes lots of allocations or could profit from cache locality pimpl may make it worse.

Answer (score 0):

`move` semantics is efficient when state can be efficiently moved.

This is sort of circular, but in the case where your state is a large amount of binary data owned "locally" in the structure, movement requires that this binary data be duplicated in the destination structure.

`std::vector` doesn't own large amounts of binary data locally.  Instead, it owns a contiguous heap-allocated buffer.  This buffer can change ownership, so `move` semantics is extremely efficient.

`move` semantics is also useful when you can save on work.  When you `move` a `std::shared_ptr`, it can avoid doing atomic increment/decrement on the reference counted data.  This prevents contention (all atomic operations cause contention), increases locality (no heap access), and even though it modifies *more* data than a `copy`, it is worthwhile.

If you want efficient `move` semantics, move your large amounts of binary data to the heap.  One way to do this easily is to store a `std::unique_ptr<POD_data>` and manually copy it when a copy is requested (requiring a heap allocation).  Another method is a `std::shared_ptr<POD_data>`, and have some kind of copy-on-write access technique.

Note, however, that many kinds of data do not actually need copy semantics.  Implement the `std::unique_ptr<POD_data>` version, and *block* your copy constructor.  Provide a method `MakeCopy` that produces a copy for the rare situations where you actually want to duplicate your large chunk of memory.  This will make efficient use of your structure easy, and inefficient use hard and easy to track down.

You will either have to guard access to the `POD_data` via conditionals, or accept a heap allocation on the `move`d-from version or your data.  I would recommend a method that returns a `POD_data&` that checks for the `unique_ptr` being valid, and if not allocates a fresh `POD_data`: the predictable branch won't be a heavy performance hit, and users can cache the `POD_data&` if they are using it many times in a row.

If the memory in the `POD_data` is large enough that blitting it around is expensive, the costs to access it via a pointer will often be modest, while the savings of not having to copy it around can be significant.